# Button is displaying above at the time of page loading

Tags: html, css

if we visit this [page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , at the time of loading , "ADD TO CART" button will display bit above as below image.

[image]

once the page loaded completely, than it will display in proper place.

[image]

but at the time of page loading also i want to display in proper place.

```
.label {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.product-view .add-to-cart .qty-wrapper label {
    line-height: 40px;
}

.qty-wrapper, .product-view .add-to-cart .qty-wrapper label {
    margin-right: 7px;
    float: left;
}

.product-view .add-to-cart-buttons {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try to resize your page http://joxi.ru/82QO0vwt1xlgMr

Comment: @3rdthemagical i guess in small screen devices or monitors it will display like this as it is not responsive, seems need to do lot of modifications to fix that, right ?

Comment: You used position: relative in many divs, you shouldn't do that! The layout you created is not looking good. You should use float for a better layout. Remove those positions!

Comment: To solve your problems you should remove all unused code from your page. Html should be clean. Now it's hard to find something in html.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi is i need to use `absolute` instead of that ?

Comment: No no! Just use float left for each section, and you can add position relative, but not use bottom or top property!

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi can you please tell me some modifications which code i need to replace with which code, when i am trying to do some changes using float property, page design is not displaying properly.

Comment: @3rdthemagical all html code is required as they are responsible for some features.

Comment: @3rdthemagical Thanks a lot for guiding me in right path

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi Thanks a lot for guiding me in right path

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi We made some changes as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) can you please check the code quality.

Comment: @3rdthemagical We made some changes as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) can you please check the code quality.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe, there are still some bugs. Why did you put scripts inside of div tags?! Scripts should stay in the bottom of the body!

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi its because that we bought one plugin. i will post new question soon & let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of your page hurts my eyes!!

You're loading the styles `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/skin/frontend/rwd/Style/css/styles.css" media="all" />` after all the js files, move the CSS below the `<meta property="og:image" ...` meta tag in your page, above all the js files.

Comment: we are not using `<meta property="og:image" ...` this is page phtml code :  http://pasted.co/67ab3648 & you already posted css code in question.

Comment: i understood from your answer that code level is in worst condition. is there any possibilty to find solution for my problem that i posted in question

Comment: "The source code of your page hurts my eyes!" - you are absolutely right!

Comment: We made some changes as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) can you please check the code quality.